# What is the font used by Nature magazine? How can we get the same or similar text font and math font in LaTex?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, pdftex, fontspec

For example, in this paper:

http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v529/n7587/pdf/nature16961.pdf

How can we get the same or similar text font and math font in LaTex?

Comment: Looks like Nimbus Roman and Minion Pro (?)

Comment: The PDF uses proprietary math fonts “Glosa Math”, ”Euclid Symbol” and several other commercial fonts.